# Show an object in Combobox

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

I have this method, it receive an Collection of an object (EmployeeState) this object contains this properties: IdEmployeeState(int), StateName(string), and Description(string) , and I need show in a combobox ONLY the StateName. This is the method. The problem with this query linq is that show all the column, like this: {StateName = Active}
                                                        {StateName = NotActive}
                                                        {StateName = Dismissed}

And I need show in Combobox only the name: "**Active**", "**Not Active**", and "**Dismissed**". keeping the object loaded into the combobox (**NOT pass it to a list of string**)

How can I do this?

```
        public void loadEmployeeStateCombobox(ICollection<EmployeeState> employeeStateCollection)
        {           
            var result = from employeeState in employeeStateCollection
                         select new
                         {
                            //employeeState.StateName,
                            bb = employeeState.StateName
                         };

            _employeeStatecomboBox.ItemsSource = result.ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to use Distinct to do not repeat the State in your combo :

```
 _employeeStatecomboBox.ItemsSource = 
                employeeStateCollection.Select(e => e.StateName).Distinct();
```

ComboxBox in WinForm require to have DisplayMember and ValueMember. The code below show you how to set the value and the display with the same value but you can also set the value to the unique identifier of the state.

```
        _employeeStatecomboBox.DataSource = employeeStateCollection.Select(e => e.StateName).Distinct();
        _employeeStatecomboBox.DisplayMember = "StateName";
        _employeeStatecomboBox.ValueMember = "StateName";
```

The same thing exist with ASP.NET but it's from my memory "DataTextField" and "DataValueField".

Comment: yes that work, the problem is in the combobox load string types, how can I keep the object EmployeeState? Or parsing to EmployeeState?

Comment: I added some information. Can you tell me if you are WinForm or Asp.Net (webform)?

Comment: You should tag WPF maybe? The same principle must be there with WPF. As a programmer I think you get the principle that a Display and Value member is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void loadEmployeeStateCombobox(ICollection<EmployeeState> employeeStateCollection)
        {           
            var result = from employeeState in employeeStateCollection
                         select new SelectListItem 
                         {
                            //employeeState.StateName,
                            Value = employeeState.Id,//whatever the id prop is
                            Text=employeeState.StateName
                         };

            _employeeStatecomboBox.ItemsSource = result.ToList();
        }
```

Or create a Dictionary, that should also work.

Comment: What contains the class SelectListItem? or explain better about the dictionary.

Comment: When binding to controls I personally always prefer to bind to object with an Id and a display prop, in case you'll need to select it. You can achieve it by both SelectedListItem or Dictionary.